# How to dynmically append html in td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tr like this

```
<tr>
   <td><input id="checked1" type="checkbox" class="cd" value="1" style="margin:6px 0 0 0;"></td>
   <td style="padding:6px 0 0 0;"><b>Staff Courtesy</b></td>
   <td>
      <select name="questionType" id="questionType" class="qType QSelect" style="padding:3px;">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
         <option value="1">text</option>
         <option value="2">rating</option>
         <option value="3">boolean</option>
         <option class="show-checkboxes" value="4">option</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td width="35%" style="padding:10px 0 0 0;" class="Fsize12 out" id="a1">Enter Some Text</td>
   <td><input type="hidden" id="optionInputa1"></td>
</tr>
```

Initially the 3rd td does not show anything but if the drop down changes then some text appears in the 3rd td

For example if text is selected then in the 3rd td it will show *place for text*.The code for it is as below

```
var option='<a href="#" class="checkbox-inline" onclick="getModal(this)">Get Options</a>';
     var txt = 'Enter Some Text';
     var bool = 'Yes or No';
     var rating='place for rating';
     $('#addNew .QSelect').change(function () { //alert(this.value);
         if (this.value == '4') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(option);
         if (this.value == '1') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(txt);
         if (this.value == '3') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(bool);
         if (this.value == '2') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(rating);
     });

     $('#addNew .QSelect').change(function() {
            var cbs = $(this).closest('td').next().children();
            if ($('.show-checkboxes', $(this)).is(':selected')) {
                $(cbs).show();
            } else {
                $(cbs).hide();
            }
        }).trigger('change');

        $('#addNew .cd').change(function() {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
           // $('#optionSave').removeAttr('disabled');
           if ($(".cd:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{

               $('#optionSave').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else
{

    $('#optionSave').attr('disabled',true);
}
            $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('select, input').prop('disabled', !checked); 
        }).trigger('change');
}
```

**My problem**
I want to programatically set the value of dropdown.For example if I want to set the drop to text then I have to set it value to 1.

This is the code for it

```
$.each(data1.savedQuestionTypesList, function(index, currQueTyp) {
                    console.log("queeeeeeeeeeeee  "+currQueTyp.pqid.qid.id + "qtid name"+currQueTyp.qtid.name);
                    $('#checked'+currQueTyp.pqid.qid.id).closest('tr').find('select').val(currQueTyp.qtid.id);


                });
```

So as the drop down value changes so also the the 3rd td changes.

For example

in the above each loop if `currQueTyp.pqid.qid.id=1` and `currQueTyp.qtid.id=1` then the dropdown is changed to `text` and in the 3rd td *place for text* will appear.

But if I do with a button then why the 3rd td does not change.

For example there is button

```
<button type="button" id="testButton">test</button> and upon clicking I want to change the drop down value

$('#testButton').click(function(){

                    $('#checked1').closest('tr').find('select').val(1);

});
```

So here the dropdown value changes but the 3rd td does not change

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/172/)

Comment: Checkboxes with similar ID? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/175/)**

Use this for the button event,

- In your case `#checked1` was a totally wrong selector. You had multiple checkboxes with same Ids. That won't work. Use class selector in such case.
- And you need the checked checkbox so `:checked`.

---

```
$('#testButton').click(function(){

    $('.cd:checked').closest('tr').find('select').val(1).change();

});
```

Comment: I have only one id for one checkbox

Comment: Please check your HTML, All checkboxes have ID as `checked1`

Comment: I dont understand which checkbox you are referring to

Comment: inspect the checkboxes staff courtesy, staff response, checkin in your console.